# generating version tags using semantic-release without the v

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, semantic-release

How can I use git tags with the format **major**.**minor**.**patch**, without the "**v**" in the beginning (i.e. versions 1.0.1, 2.0.1)?

I'm using Gitlab CI, but even using the Docker image locally I'm not able to pass the value to **tag-format** correctly.

What I'm trying to do:

`npx --no-install semantic-release --tag-format "\${version}"`

---

The error log:

> [8:42:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  ETAGNOVERSION Invalid `tagFormat` option.
> The tagFormat (https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#tagformat) option must contain the variable version exactly once.
>
> Your configuration for the tagFormat option is ``.
>
> [8:42:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  EINVALIDTAGFORMAT Invalid `tagFormat` option.
> The tagFormat (https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#tagformat) must compile to a valid Git reference (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format#_description).
>
> Your configuration for the tagFormat option is ``.
>
> AggregateError:
> SemanticReleaseError: Invalid `tagFormat` option.
> at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/get-error.js:6:10)
> at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/verify.js:22:17)
> at async run (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:53:3)
> at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:259:22)
> at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js:55:5)
> SemanticReleaseError: Invalid `tagFormat` option.
> at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/get-error.js:6:10)
> at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/verify.js:29:17)
> at async run (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:53:3)
> at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:259:22)
> at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js:55:5)
> at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/verify.js:41:11)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> at async run (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:53:3)
> at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:259:22)
> at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js:55:5) {
> name: 'AggregateError'
> }npm ERR! code 1

When it says **the tagFormat option is ``**, it's as if the **${version}** is being replaced by empty space...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `npx` code, but it sure does look like this got shell-`eval`-ed twice. If that's the case, perhaps `\\\$` instead of just `\$` will do the trick.

Comment: Or you can also use single quote to avoid any shell interpretation of the parameter.

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Comment: npx semantic-release --branches main --tag-format "\${version}" works for me on MacOS Iterm bash shell

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue we set the tagFormat in the the release.config.js configuration file:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    tagFormat: '${version}',
    ....
}
```